# What is the reason for commutative property during multiplication of real numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic

This may seem like a really stupid question, but I am unable to rationalize with myself as to why the commutative property exists when multiplying 2 real number.

Take for example:

$2 * 5 = 10$

This actually means that if we add $2$ $5$ times we will get $10$.

But its kind of amazing when we can say for sure that if we add $5$ $2$ times we will also get $10$.

What is the reason for this property, I know I may be over-thinking this, but I can't understand intuitively why this happens.

I know that $5$ actually "contains" $2$ but how does that guarantee commutative property ?

For example matrix multiplication is not commutative, yet real number multiplication is.

Am I just overthinking something simple?

Need some clarity.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to explain that multiplication over the natural numbers is commutative for you? If so, we have this -- https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Natural_Number_Multiplication_is_Commutative

Comment: If you want an answer to a question so basic in nature, you need to have a solid, formal definition of what multiplication means. And to do that, you need a solid, formal definition of what numbers are. And you need to decide whether you want to think about integers or about real numbers. So, with that in mind, what does $2$ _really mean_ to you?

Comment: It's a good question. Why intuitively is it the case that multiplication is commutative? I wouldn't say it's _entirely_ obvious that $\overbrace{m+ \cdots + m}^{\text{n times}} = \overbrace{n + \cdots + n}^{\text{m times}}$

Comment: As for matrix multiplication, it is important to keep in mind that these kinds of "multiplication" are not the same. It ties into the notion of algebraic objects. Typically, a set of numbers, equipped with two operations, has one of the two operations denoted the "multiplicative" operation, and the other the "additive" operation. If the set with these two operations meet certain conditions, it is called a "field". (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics))

Comment: We require multiplication commutative in fields, so in that sense matrix multiplication doesn't commute because the set of matrices is not a field. You could also argue it's a consequence of how matrix multiplication is defined, and that calling it "multiplication" was a poor choice owing to how it's not really multiplication in the usual sense (luckily most people precede it by saying "matrix" so it's clear).

Comment: @Arthur Yes. How would do I understand this? What do I do?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Yes but why does that happen? Thats my question.

Comment: [This picture](http://www.rpdp.net/mathdictionary/english/vmd/mirror/c/vepropertyofmultiplication.gif) might help.

Comment: "Yes but why does that happen?" -- In my class on set theory, we proved multiplication is commutative over the naturals through use of the Peano axioms and the use of the successor function. In the case of real numbers, we didn't prove it, but I imagine it would tie into showing that, given the sequences $(a_n),(b_n)$ are Cauchy and represent $a,b$ in the reals respectively, that $(a_n b_n)$ and $(b_n a_n)$ are both Cauchy sequences and the same sequence (which wouldn't be hard.)

Comment: @KM101 Your link does not work, getting a 404.

Comment: So in that sense, really, there are a lot of ways to prove what you're looking at. It all depends on the scope of your question (how deep do you want to go?) and what is your understanding of all the various topics we're throwing at you? We're not doing this to be dicks or anything, it's just that this is a REALLY good question but answering it requires getting right down to definitions and pinning all the details exactly. Which might be why we might be seemingly unnecessarily vague or bouncing around the points.

Comment: It’s a picture of an $m \times n$ rectangle. If it is rotated by $90°$, you get an $n \times m$ rectangle, but the area is the same. So adding $n$ to itself $m$ times is the same as adding $m$ to itself $n$ times.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Thank you so much. I know you aren't trying to be offensive or anything. In fact your comments provide an indication as to how deep this "simple" topic really is. I don't want to disappoint you but I simply don't have the mathematical training to understand the concepts that you are talking about. I just an amateur dabbling here. Seems I bit of more than I could chew here. Could you at least point me in the right direction, as to which branch of mathematics this topic falls in, so that may be I can make some baby steps in that direction?

Comment: @KM101 AH! But you are already assuming $m * n$ = $n*m$ that's how you know the areas are equal but the question becomes why is $ m * n$ = $n * m$. Do you understand the question?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer As far as how far I want to go, is ideally until I get a solid understanding, but I don't think I will be able to do that, as it deals with concepts that are way too abstract for me to learn. Do you think the title could be better?

Comment: Yeah, I do. I assume the areas are the same because the rectangle is simply being translated/rotated.

Comment: @KM101 Good Point!!

Comment: Hmmm... Well, the topics regarding operations, what commutativity is, and the study of sets equipped with operations, and proving it for operations in general was something discussed in my course on algebraic structures (so texts on abstract algebra would help). Discussions on the Peano axioms and a broad overview of the properties of sets would be found in a basic set theory or proof-writing course. Looking at what a real number actually "is" would be discussed in classes on real analysis.

Comment: So even looking into this topic on your own wouldn't be particularly easy since it's sort of in an overlap of various different parts of mathematics (abstract algebra, set theory, and real analysis) - and all these are topics that are usually delved into by math majors in undergrad. Explaining the necessary concepts for this question to be properly answered might be a bit much depending on your level.

Comment: "Do you think the title could be better?" -- The title seems fine. The issues with your question have nothing to do with how you're asking it. It's just that this is the kind of question that, while you can phrase or say it really really simply, the answer is really, really complicated. (Of course, asking questions like these is also a good thing because commutativity is something we take for granted a lot, for example, but I imagine very few people know it can be rigorously justified. :p)

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Then what should I do now? You know the worst part is? Now that I know that there are actually proofs regarding this fact, I can no longer remain blissfully ignorant as everyone else. And knowing that these topics are well beyond my reach, will continue to torment me for the rest of my life. So the question that I am asking is - what would you do if you were alone, untrained and wanted to understand something like this by yourself, how would you go about it?  What would you do then?

Comment: It depends, really, on how old you are and your present understanding of mathematics, and your desire to learn more. For example, were you a teenager, and really liked math, I would suggesting minoring or majoring in mathematics when you go to college; they can probably eventually give you the foundations to understand this material than any amount of self-study would. The courses I mentioned are typically aimed are math majors in their 2nd-4th years.

Comment: If college isn't a possibility, or  you really don't want to wait, I would perhaps find a book on elementary set theory or elementary number theory. They're good starting points for proof-based mathematics (or, at least, they're the first proof-based courses I see at universities). From there, you would probably go on through a quick text on abstact algebra or algebraic structures, and then a text on real analysis. In self-study, though, be ready to ask lots of questions and sometimes get stuck, but at least places like MSE exist as a means of asking your questions.

Comment: But this all speaks to how I like to learn about topics - I'd be the type to pick up the book and barrel through it to the best of my ability, but I've always gotten my best understanding in classes. What works best for you or is the most convenient might be different.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Math is kind of an amateur hobby for me. College isn't a possibility, since I am already 28 and majored in Computer Applications.

Comment: @ng.newbie: For me, the real question is how come that even for the natural numbers, exponentiation $(a, b) \mapsto a^b$, which is the next level operation defined by repetition of a base operation, is *not* commutative (neither is associative). How come? We're just doing the same to multiplication as to addition..

Comment: I suggest you read Landau's lovely book "Foundations of Analysis". Don't be frightened by the title.

Answer (score 3):

Is $17 \times 19$ equal to $19 \times 17$? This is not obvious, until we draw a certain picture, and then it does become quite obvious.

Draw a rectangular array of dots with 17 rows and 19 columns. If we group the dots row by row, then we have 17 groups of 19. On the other hand, if we group the dots column by column, then we have 19 groups of 17. Thus, 17 of 19 is the same thing as 19 of 17.

Answer (score 3):

```
 * * * * *
 * * * * *
```

In this picture there are five columns of two stars each, so in total there are $2+2+2+2+2$ stars.

On the other hand, there are also two rows of five stars each, so in total there are $5+5$ stars.

Since the number of stars has to be the same no matter how we count them -- they're the same stars! -- it must necessarily be that $2+2+2+2+2=5+5$.

The fact that if you count the same things in different orders you will get the same number is arguably the *most fundamental property* of "counting". It is a practical experience that ought to be supported by plenty of actual examples in elementary school. I doubt it can be reduced to something that feels more fundamental than counting itself does.

Comment: Enumeration of the dots may give us natural numbers.  But, I'm not convinced that they give us real numbers, and this question concerns real numbers, not natural numbers.

Answer (score 1):

For thousands of years before if could be formally proven, the commutativity of addition and multiplication was held to be "common sense" based on experience with countless examples.  Today, it could even be used as a kind of test of any formal definition of numbers (natural or real), addition and multiplication. If you could not prove these and other "common sense" properties using these definitions, they would  clearly be inadequate.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of it like this maybe: 2 times 5 is the total size of 5 sets with 2 elements each, whereas 5 times 2 is the total size of 2 sets with 5 elements each. To see that these represent the total same number of elements, we see that we can match up the first item of the third set in the first product with the third item of the first set in the second product, and the second item of the fourth set in the first product with the fourth item of the second set in the second product, etc. If we can pair up the items in two groups one by one, they must have the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Note:- I am providing this answer using the example. If any could generalise it, i shall be grateful to him. :)
Prove that $14×11=11×14$. (I suppose that you know mxn is n added m times)

Proof-: $11×14=(11×11)+(11×3)$.....(1)
Let $3×11=11×3$.
So, the eq.(1) becomes =$(11×11)+(3×11)=14×11$. Proved.

But, here we supposed that $3×11=11×3$. We need to prove the same.
So, consider $11×3=(3×3)+(8×3)$....(2)
Let $8×3=3×8$. 
So, (2) becomes $11×3=(3×3)+(3×8)=3×11$. Proved.

But in the latter we considered that $8×3=3×8$. So, we need to prove the same. In the similar manner, we prove that $8×3=3×8$, but supposing that $3×5=5×3$. So, we need to prove this now. We shall prove this in the similar manner supposing that $3×2=2×3$. Now, we need to prove this. We prove this in the similar manner and at an intermediate step, we suppose that $2×1=1×2$. But look at this. Do you believe in $n×1$ i.e. n  equals $1×n$, that is $1$ added n times. So, you would always end up supposing $c×1=1×c$, which is true by the definition of natural numbers. Therefore, we proved that $14×11=11×14$. Now, its your turn to generalise this for the following statement.

For some +ve integers $a,b$,$a×b=b×a$.